# Can't see the Username and hostname in terminal

Tags: bashrc, hostname, user-profile

While I'm Opening a New Terminal i Used to get like this before

```
sysadmin@system99:~$
```

But now i get like this below

```
-bash-4.2$
```

Seems .bashrc issue, so what i copied bashrc from

```
cp /etc/skel/* ~
```

But this too not yet fixed my issue , how can i fix it ?

Guide me buddies..

Comment: post the output of `cat /etc/hosts` and `cat /etc/hostname` commands

Comment: Got fixed Avinash machi , copied .bashrc file from other host to that particular host.

Comment: Tamil Nadu, Nagercoil, Come to your chat please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open you `~/.bashrc` file and search for the following text(this starts from line no 59 on my `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\w\$ '
fi
```

and then change the PS1 variable in the `else` part to:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Comment: yes its fixed by replacing a .bashrc